# Having trouble with word function

Tags: c, function

I am having trouble with creating a function that registers input as a word. Currently it's registering words, but anything with a ' (as in don't, won't can't) is showing as 2 words. The program should take input from a file, count the words and display the word count and average letters per word.

I have played around with the code for a bit and nothing seems to solve the issue, but the following code is the closest to being correct as I have gotten.

```
int main(void) {
  int ch, wordCount, wordAverage, letterCount;
  bool inword = false;
  wordCount = 0;
  letterCount = 0;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (isalpha(ch)) {
      letterCount++;

      if (!isspace(ch) && (!inword)) {
        inword = true;
        wordCount++;
      }
    } else
      inword = false;

  }
  wordAverage = letterCount / wordCount;

  printf("The number of words was %d, and the average letters per word was %d.", wordCount, wordAverage);
}
```

Comment: `with a ' (as in don't, won't can't)` - so change the `isalpha(ch)` allowed characters in a word to something like `(isalpha(ch) || ch == '\'')`

Comment: Thanks! That corrected my function.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `isalpha`

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (isalpha(ch)) {
      letterCount++;
```

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) states `isalpha` is equivalent to `isupper` || `islower`.
Try :

`isalpha(ch) || ispunct(ch)`.